# How to export a 2-dimensional matrix into a csv file in Python?

Tags: python, csv, matrix

I have a 2-D matrix and I want to export it somehow with my python script into a CSV, is there a fast and elegant way for that?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190612/how-to-write-python-array-data-to-excel

Answer (score 0):

If your 2D matrix is a numpy array you can use [numpy.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) with a delimiter set as ','.